# spring hibernate - unit testing dao

Tags: spring, hibernate, unit-testing

I am trying to unit test my DAOs, but i'm having some trouble.

First off, my DAO has 1 method: a `findById` type method.  i want to write a unit test for this.  so, my line of thinking is:

- in order to test this method, i need to insert a known entity
- call `findById()` on the DAO,
- and then assert that what i get back is what i originally inserted.

Now, the part i'm having a hard time with is trying to figure out how to do the insert.

My concerns:

1. I currently don't have an `insert` method in my DAO. I could write one, but i don't see the point in doing it simply for the sake of testing.
2. The other possibility is to use the Hibernate API (ie HibernateTemplate) to perform the insert.  But, i want my unit tests to be flexible.  I don't want to tie my unit tests to any specific API.

What should i do?

Comment: Have a quick Google of Mockito - it's a testing framework that lets you mock results.  It doesn't answer your query entirely but it's definitely a place to start looking.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your database (i prefer an in-memory variant for testing), you should be able to pre-populate the database and set it to a known state before each individual test. So there's no need for an `insert` method just to do testing. I have used HSQLDB (which is now superseeded by another database which I don't remember the name of right now) for this many times, and I usually create the database and run some insert SQL statements to populate the database before each test. There are also frameworks for this, like [DbUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/).

**Edit**

The database I was thinking of was [H2](http://www.h2database.com). It seems like it also has a neat feature that it can [execute a script when a connection is made](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#execute_sql_on_connection)

```
String url = "jdbc:h2:mem;INIT=runscript from '~/create.sql'\\;runscript from '~/populate.sql'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally I do not write unit tests for my DAOs. I prefer to test this area via integration/functional testing.

If you want to then one option is to pre-populate the database so your unit test case know what to expect from the database.

Spring provides excellent DAO layer test framework where the data changes are rolled back so that one test does not impact other due to data change.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [Spring's support for embedded databases](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-embedded-database-support) when configuring the spring context of your integration test. The `<jdbc:script>` tag allows you to execute init and destroy scripts:

```
<jdbc:embedded-database type="H2" id="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script execution="INIT" location="setup.sql"/>
    <jdbc:script execution="DESTROY" location="teardown.sql"/>
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

Comment: thanks, i used an embedded DB, and it seems to work pretty well.  though, i'm having problems at start up.  I'm working with hibernate so my db schema is in my mapping files, which means I shouldn't have to write a bunch of CREATE TABLE statements.  But, if i run my unit test, i'll get an exception saying XXX table doesn't exist.  what seems to be happening is it's running my insert statements before creating the schema. how do i fix this?  thanks again!

Comment: I think every solution for this problem will have some price. In this case the price is that you need to maintain the schema creation script, but it's not so bad: 1) Hibernate basically outputs the script when using `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop` with `hibernate.show_sql=true`; 2) I think you can have multiple init `<script>` tags in the above xml config, so you can just dump hibernate's output in a localized `schema.sql` script; 3) once your schema gets stable, there is no need to touch this file very often.

Comment: Other solutions like DBUnit will require comparable amount of work (or even more), so it basically comes down to your personal preference which way you go, but there will be some inconvenience involved anyway, I'm afraid.